# adobe cq publish live copy page based on another live copy page

Tags: aem

I have an Adobe CQ 5.5 with site structure like that:

```
/content/mysite/en      (blueprint)
/content/mysite/en_us       (live copy of ‘en’)
/content/mysite/en_cn       (live copy of ‘en’)
```

EN_US and EN_AP have approximately the same number of authored pages. However, the number of published pages are different. 
I need to add a new live copy and publish it:

```
/content/mysite/zh_cn       (live copy of ‘en’)
```

ZH_CN should have the same pages published as EN_CN.

How can I achieve that without manually comparing each page in EN_CN and EN_CN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your rollout configuration for your 2nd live copy based on your 1st live copy. You can do the following :

1) set trigger action as On Activation. This will ensure that it triggers your sync action as soon as the livecopy is activated/published.

2) set the synchronization action as "targetActivate". This will ensure that your 2nd livecopy is activated as soon as the trigger action 1) happens.

Comment: thanks.  This was very helpful.  With the info you and Alexander provided above, I was able to successfully implement the RollOut config.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create live copy for zh_cn, but there is no OOTB way how to activate necessary pages similar with en_cn. But for that you can setup groovyconsole (https://github.com/Citytechinc/cq-groovy-console) , write pretty easy groovy script which traverses "en_cn" nodes, checks their publish status and activates corresponding nodes under "zh_cn". This is disposable action.

In order to maintain publish action on en_cn level and reflect it on zh_cn, and for not to run script time to time, you really need to create a rollout config for page activation and deactivation and setup it on "en_cn" node. How to do it read here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/sites/multi-site-manager/msm-sync.html

Comment: I started down the Groovy path. Unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough to get it working correctly.   I did successfully implement the RollOut config you referred me to.   Thank you. It was very helpful.